# SQL HTML email showing blank when one table has no results

Tags: sql, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

The following code sends 2 diferent tables based on an sql query through the function sp_send_dbmail , the catch is , if both tables return results , the email shows up without any problem , perfectly. If one of the tables has **NO** results, the email comes up completly blank.

How can i fix this?

Thanks

```
 declare @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX);


set @tableHTML = N'Este foi o resultado de Faturas Emitidas: <br><br><table border ="1">' +
N'<tr><th>Documento</th></tr>' +
cast (( select td = cc.tx 
                from cc
 for xml path ('tr'),type) as nvarchar(max)) +

 N' </table><table border ="1"><tr><th>Valor Total Vencido</th></tr>' 
 +
 cast (( select td = fx.tc
                        from fx
  for xml path ('tr'),type) as nvarchar(max)) +
  N'</table>';

 EXEC sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name ='xx_SqlMail',
      @recipients ='ccccc@hotmail.com',
      @subject ='Resumo',
      @body =@tableHTML,
      @body_format='HTML';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that part of your query is returning a NULL value.  Concatenating any value with a NULL will always result in NULL.

SELECT 'A' + NULL + 'B' will return NULL.

As you are doing multiple concatenations it would mean that if any value is NULL then @tableHTML will be NULL.  Try wrapping your selects in an ISNULL().

select ISNULL(td, '') = cc.tx ...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i get the same problem after wrapping every select field with isnull, this is very strange since i really thought your answer was going to solve the problem

Comment: Could you put a PRINT @tableHTML instead of the EXEC sp_send_dbmail to see what is returned in your variable?

Answer (score 0):

Any table in your concatenation that returns a NULL will make the entire concatenation NULL.

To resolve this, just wrap each section that could potentially be NULL with an ISNULL().

I had a similar issue where I was running two separate queries and building two tables that I wanted to include in the body of the email.  One would occasionally return no values and the email would come back blank. Using ISNULL fixed it for me.

See the code below for an example of what I did:

```
set @tablesHTML = **ISNULL**(@tableOneHTML,'NO RESULTS') 
                + **ISNULL**(@tableTwoHTML,'NO RESULTS')

exec XXXXXX.[XXX].[sp_send_dbmail] 
        @profile_name='Mail'
        ,@recipients = @EmailRecipients
        ,@copy_recipients= @EmailCopyRecipients 
        ,@subject = 'Email Subject Here'  
        ,@body = @tablesHTML
        ,@body_format = 'HTML'
```